# Ticker is taking focus away

Tags: c#, timer, focus

I have a timer updating a progressbar in my code. It updates every second. But, when I try to do anything in the app (like selecting an item from combobox), I cant do it, because as soon as the ticker updates, the combobox closes, so I have at most one second to do so. How can I stop the ticker taking the focus on itself every second? (I guess thats the reason..)

Okay, since it seems I cant properly format the code in comment, I put it here:
in `Form1_load()`:

```
        Timer ticker = new Timer();
        ticker.Interval = 1000;
        ticker.Tick += new EventHandler(ticker_Tick);
        ticker.Start();
```

and here the timer method:

```
        string time = string.Empty;
        int a = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode cas in UpdateFlights)
        {
            time = cas.Attributes.GetNamedItem("time").Value;
            a = Int32.Parse(time);
        }
        toolStripProgressBar1.Step = 3;
        toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = a * 3;
        toolStripProgressBar1.PerformStep();
```

Comment: What does your timer's Tick event code look like.

Comment: A "ticker"? Do you mean a `Timer`?  Also, you should try to show us some code, because by default this shouldn't happen, because the `Timer` won't be able to receive focus.

Comment: That is an odd behavior, can you post some source code?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, Its `Timer`.
in `Form1_Load()` is
`        Timer ticker = new Timer();
     ticker.Interval = 1000;
     ticker.Tick += new EventHandler(ticker_Tick);
     ticker.Start();`
and here is the method itself:
`    string time = string.Empty;
     int a = 0;
     foreach (XmlNode cas in UpdateFlights)
            {
                time = cas.Attributes.GetNamedItem("time").Value;
                a = Int32.Parse(time);
            }
            toolStripProgressBar1.Step = 3;
            toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = a * 3;
            toolStripProgressBar1.PerformStep();`

Comment: a is time in seconds i get from an xml file, it is the time when the statusbar is supposed to reset to zero(that is in IF just after this, didnt include this, tell me if it is needed here)

Comment: Is it, possibly, because setting `Maximum` causes the progress bar control to be redrawn? Is something in your paint handler causing the entire form to be invalidated, and subsequently redrawn?

Comment: Resolved, Im feeling quite stupid now, after going through whole the code several times I noticed that digged in several IF conditions, I was setting the focus to some other control... Sorry for bothering you with this, and thanks for help.